# Setting the PHP SESSION user ID in my login function

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I was wondering if someone could please help me with my login function. Currently it will check to see if the username and password match an entry in the members table and if it does then sets the session variable authorised to true.
What Id like help with is when the session variable authorised has been set, I want to also set a user ID session variable, and by user ID I mean the numeric value - not the username which is in a column of the members table named memberID.

```
    <?php
    function login($user, $pass){

       //strip all tags from varible   
       $user = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($user));
       $pass = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($pass));

       $pass = md5($pass);

       // check if the username and password combination exist in database
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$pass'";
       $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed. ' . mysql_error());

       if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
          // the username and password match,
          // set the session
          $_SESSION['authorized'] = true;

          // direct to admin
          header('Location: '.DIRADMIN);
          exit();
       } else {
        // define an error message
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Sorry, wrong username or password';
       }
    }
    ?>
```

Please note, I am aware that `md5()` isn't the best method for password encryption and `mysql_real_escape_string()` and `mysql_num_rows()` are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the column name in your DB is userId, all you have to do is add

```
$_SESSION['userId'] = $result['userId'];
```

under the line where you set the session.

So, it will look like

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
      // the username and password match,
      // set the session
      $_SESSION['authorized'] = true;
      //set User Id
      $_SESSION['userId'] = $result['userId']; 

      // direct to admin
      header('Location: '.DIRADMIN);
      exit();
 }
```

Comment: The user ID column is memberID so I have done the following:
$_SESSION['memberID'] = $result['memberID'];

But when I try to echo the session variable, I get nothing.
echo $_SESSION['memberID'];

Shouldn't I be adding memberID into the query somewhere?

Comment: No, since your query is "SELECT * ", you are getting all columns. For debugging purposes, can you tell me what `$result` looks like?. Just save `$_SESSION['result']=$result` and then do a `var_dump($_SESSION['result'])`

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION['result']; returns int(0)

Comment: so i'm guessing your query doesn't return any results. Look into that.

Comment: Thank you for your input. When I var_dump the session variable memberID, I get NULL. I can't see why this isn't working when I know the members table has just 1 row and that row consists of memberID with value 1, username with value admin and password with value (md5 hash). Similarly, when I var_dump $result, I get int(0). I tried setting a session variable for username but I still get NULL. It doesn't make sense as it had to verify that these values existed before it would authenticate.